# Run multiple independent python scripts with slurm in one node

Tags: slurm

I have a problem to run multiple python script in the same node. Normally my scripts would looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1 
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --job-name=debug
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
source .venv/bin/activate # activate enviroment

python test.py --args=...
```

So how do I change my shell script, such that I can run multiple
`python test.py --args=...` in the same node. The reason is that, it does not need a lot of GPU to run, and you can think that the python scripts are independent experiments (not fine tuning).

So I think of changing `ntasks=4` ( to run 4 experiments).

Answer (score 0):

If the four Python scripts can work at the same time on the same GPU, you can change the submission script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1 
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --job-name=debug
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
source .venv/bin/activate # activate environment

srun python test.py --args=...
```

The `srun` will start four independent instances of `python test.py. This will make sense only if` test.py`is starting from a random initial seed or if it reads the value of the`SLURM_PROCID`environment variable. The value of`--args=...` cannot be made dependent on the task ID.

Comment: Can I also used: `srun python test.py --args=args_1 & srun python test.py --args=args_2`? And the args here are the arguments I give to my python script.

Comment: It would be better in that case to use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).